# problem with printf

Tags: c

...

```
uint64_t                 expires_time;
ngx_memcpy(data, in, in_len);
data_size = in_len + sizeof(expires_time);
expires_time = (uint64_t) now;
expires_time = ngx_http_encrypted_session_htonll(expires_time);
ngx_memcpy(data + in_len, (u_char *) &expires_time, sizeof(expires_time));
MD5(data, data_size, p);

static inline uint64_t

ngx_http_encrypted_session_htonll(uint64_t n) {
#ifdef htonll
return htonll(n);
# else
return ((uint64_t) htonl(n) > 32);
#endif
}
```

Why I want to try `printf("%s",data)` result: in. `ngx_memcpy` should be add `expires_time` for this string ? How to see md5 in string length `data_size`  ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. Can you at least indent your source code? I think I forgot how to read it otherwise.

Comment: You should be clear and precise about what you want to know buddy, else what you will get is only downvote!

Comment: Nooo my eyes!! Please, remove all the useless casts.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to print a string. Whereas your data is not null terminated. Just loop for data_size and print each byte in data as hex value.